# Euler method fails to approximate the exact solution $y(x)=(2x/3)^{3/2}$

Tags: numerical-methods

How can I show that the Euler method fails to approximate the exact solution 
$$y(x)=(2x/3)^{3/2}$$ 
to the IVP 
$$y'=y^\frac{1}{3}$$
$$y(0)=0$$

Here we have $f(t,y)= y^\frac{1}{3}$,  $y_0=0$ and so $f(t_0,y_0)=f(0,0)=0$ and 
$$y_{n+1}=y_n +h f(t_n,y_n)$$
Thus
$$y_1=0 \\
y_2=0 \\
\vdots\\
y_n=0$$

So, I can't understand why it fails. Could you help me?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  Please, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information about typesetting math on this site.  I know it takes a little work, but it makes things much easier to read (and therefore makes it much more likely that you will get help!)

Comment: That initial value problem has more than one solution. The Euler method exactly produces one of the solutions.

Comment: @ali: was that really the initial condition? If you move it away from the $0$ to be something like $y(0)=0.01$, things are much better. At that point, the derivative of the function DNE.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the general solution,
$$ y(x) = \left(\frac{2x+C}{3}\right)^{3/2}$$
Can be achieved by integration:
$$\int \frac{dy }{y^{1/3}}=\int dx$$
This assumes that $y\neq 0$, which is not necessarily true. You therefore have two solutions at $x=0$, and you can't force the Euler method to "choose" the right one.

The reason you don't have a unique solution at $x=0$ is that $d(y^{1/3})/dx$ does not exist on any open interval containing $x=0$. Choosing an IV point with $x> 0$ will guarantee local uniqueness.

Comment: I am still confused. the approximation will be equal zero no matter how big n I choose, is that right ? If it is right then it means that the approximation fails because it is zero ??

Comment: @ali, hope it's clearer now. It's not that the Euler method is failing, it's that it's approximating (correctly) a second solution.